# #warning and #error as Macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

Is there a way to have macros to force warnings and errors while compiling?

I currently have something like this:

```
#if defined( __clang__ )
#   define PRAGMA( x )                    _Pragma( #x )
#elif defined( __GNUC__ )
#   define PRAGMA( x )                    _Pragma( #x )
#elif defined( _MSC_VER )
#   define PRAGMA( x )                    __pragma( x )
#endif

#define STRINGISIZE( str )    #str
#define STR( str )            STRINGISIZE( str )

#define LINE                  STR( __LINE__ )
#define FILE                  __FILE__
#define FILE_LINE             __FILE__ "(" LINE ")"

#define INFO( info , msg ) \
  PRAGMA( message( FILE_LINE ": " #info ": " msg ) )

#define MESSAGE( m )          INFO( msg , m )
#define WARNING( w )          INFO( warning , w )
#define ERROR( e )            INFO( error , e )
#define TODO( t )             INFO( TODO , t )

int main()
{
    MESSAGE( "MSG" )
    TODO( "TODO" )
    WARNING( "WARN" )
    ERROR( "ERROR" )
}
```

Visual Studio 2013 will treat these macros as warnings/errors and this example will not compile.
Is there an equivalent for GCC and Clang?

---

```
#if defined( _MSC_VER )
    #define INFO( info , msg ) \
        PRAGMA( message( FILE_LINE ": " #info ": " msg ) )
    #define MESSAGE( m )          INFO( info , m )
    #define WARNING( w )          INFO( warning , w )
    #define ERROR( e )            INFO( error , e )
    #define TODO( t )             INFO( todo t )
#elif defined( __GNUC__ ) || defined( __clang__ )
    #define INFO( info , msg ) \
        PRAGMA( #info " : " #msg ) )
    #define MESSAGE( m )          INFO( info , m )
    #define WARNING( w )          INFO( GCC warning , w )
    #define ERROR( e )            INFO( GCC error , e )
    #define TODO( t )             INFO( , "todo" t )
#endif
```

Comment: Read the documentation, man.

Comment: I really wish people would not use #pragma todo's etc they clutter the build output and never get fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. Quoting the [GCC preprocessor documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html):

> ```
> #pragma GCC warning
> #pragma GCC error
> ```
>
> `#pragma GCC warning "message"` causes the preprocessor to issue a warning diagnostic with the text ‘`message`’. The message contained in the pragma must be a single string literal. Similarly, `#pragma GCC error "message"` issues an error message. Unlike the ‘`#warning`’ and ‘`#error`’ directives, these pragmas can be embedded in preprocessor macros using ‘`_Pragma`’.

Testing shows that these work with clang too.

Note that you do not need to embed the file and line information. The directive will be output as a regular diagnostic, and all diagnostics include the file and line information already.

Depending on the specific macro in question, another option may be to force a function call to a function marked with the `warning` or `error` attributes. Unlike the pragmas, the attributes have no effect if the function call is known to be unreachable (for example because it appears in an `if` block where the condition has been detected at compile time as always being false), so if in that case you want the warning or error to be suppressed, they may be more appropriate.

Comment: was searching for like 3 hours for it now, thanks you showed it to me :-)

Comment: I use the example from the documentation `#pragma GCC warning "message"` however i get the following output: `warning: ignoring #pragma GCC warning [-Wunknown-pragmas]|` using gcc 4.7.1

Comment: @Serthy They is available starting with GCC 4.8. [Here is the GCC 4.7 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/cpp/Pragmas.html), and [here is the GCC 4.8 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/cpp/Pragmas.html) where you can see they have been added. The `warning` and `error` attributes have been available for longer, so if you cannot upgrade to GCC 4.8, you may want to use those instead.