# How to replace function name with string constant in #define macro in C

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I wish to replace a function call with a string using pre-processor directives.
Something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define Func1(arg) "Function not supported"
#endif
```

So basically when someone calls this function, I want a compilation error, such that this function is invisible in `DEBUG` mode, and in place of that , the following string is printed in the compilation log.
This method throws error. 
Is there any other means to print a particular string i want when `func1()` is called?

Comment: Please clarify "Throws error". Is it a compilation error? A runtime error? Provide the error description and the code at the usage site.

Comment: the exact error is:
"Error: expression must have (pointer-to-) function type".... This error is thrown at the location this function was called.

Comment: Is the message so important?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious way to archieve such behaviour is to use `#error` directive. However since it's not possible to construct "conditional `#error` directive" I guess next move is `_Pragma` operator introduced in C99. Here is the solution that produces a message during compilation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG 1

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define Func1(arg) _Pragma("message \"Function not supported.\"")
#endif

void (Func1)(int arg)
{
}

int main(void)
{
    Func1(1);
    Func1(2);
    Func1(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation (with `gcc`):

```
...
check.c:15: note: #pragma message: Function not supported.
check.c:16: note: #pragma message: Function not supported.
check.c:17: note: #pragma message: Function not supported.
```

I know It's not direct solution (such message is not even treated as warning, so `-Werror` doesn't change anything), however you can use e.g. `grep` tool or any other method to scan compiler's output.

Since GCC 4.8 there is also [`#pragma GCC error "message"`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html), which is direct (but non-portable) solution. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225093/586873) for more information. For example:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define Func1(arg) _Pragma("GCC error \"Function not supported.\"")
#endif
```

Comment: The issue in my case is, i need a compilation error at the place where function is called. In your solution, the preprocessor will be handled before function is actually compiled. So when handled in a sequential manner, the preprocessor won't execute.

Comment: @user3840787: The actual place where `Func1(arg)` function-like macro is "executed" is `Func1(1);` instruction in `main` definition. This doesn't matter that macro is defined, without proper invocation it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply leave the function undefined. This will result in an error at link time.

If you use gcc, you could use one of its extensions, a function attribute:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define __nodebugonly
#else
#define __nodebugonly __attribute__((error("Function not supported")))
#endif

void Func1(int arg) __nodebugonly;
```

Comment: Right, I misread your question in that regard. Since `__debugonly` would be a misnomer then I changed that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#error "Function not supported"
```

to abort the compilation.
But obviously when someone has access to the source that can be removed - so what exactly do you try to do?

If you don't trust those people with your source then don't give it to them.
Link it into an .obj, define the 'interface' with a .h and only give out that.

Comment: I could have used #error... :) But that will be called immediately when preprocessor is handled, and NOT when function is called. :( :(